# How to remove tag (untag) on deleted resource

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have deleted some AWS resources but, when I visit "Tag Editor" view in the AWS console, i can see that they are still listed. I cannot access them but, they are visible. The annoyance is that they had been tagged and when i will search for my resources by that tag, they will pollute the returned list. I have tried 2 ways to remove the tags but they both fail:

**Method 1**:

Via the Tag Editor's `Manage Tags` dashboard:

[image]

**Method 2**:

Using the `resourcegroupstaggingapi` command from the `aws` CLI tool:

```
$ aws --region eu-central-2 resourcegroupstaggingapi untag-resources --resource-arn-list arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-2:112233445566:userpool/eu-central-2_AABBCCDD --tag-keys dev2
{
    "FailedResourcesMap": {
        "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-2:112233445566:userpool/eu-central-2_AABBCCDD": {
            "StatusCode": 400,
            "ErrorCode": "ResourceNotFoundException",
            "ErrorMessage": "User pool eu-central-2_AABBCCDD does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

How do i go about removing those tags on those deleted resources?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?